# Youtube - Make play after over and Make pause after out div

Tags: jquery, youtube, fadein, fadeout

For customer specification, need a functionality that is not why it is not working.

In my site there is a picture, that making over, must be removed (keep some texts above) and load a youtube video.

concepts:

-- Over Picture

------ Is gone fadeout text

---------- Video appears FadeIn

-------------- Play Video

-- Out of the picture

------ Pause the video

---------- It is the youtube video with fadeout

-------------- The text had to fadein

I've scheduled, but the FADE on the video does not work, load the video HIT and HIT the video disappears.

Anyone who knows?

Here my development: http://www.javiscript.es/desarrollo/yppah/

Thanks and regards.

Javier

Comment: You could use [.pause() and .play() methods and .paused property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) on the video element, not to reload it over and over again. But imo that pausing on mouselave doesn't look good in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

This afternoon I will try to make mounting in HTML5 to use controls that you indicate.


Also, I have doubts, why does not the fade in the video?
Is it to be a very large video size?


Greetings.